# How to add Idea module to dependencies for gradle

Tags: java, gradle, module

I've a gradle module called "Service" and module called ProtocolLibrary, generated by Idea. How can I add library module to my main module?

I have tryed to simply add source dir to project:

```
main {
    java.srcDirs      = ['src/main/java', '../ProtocolLibrary/src']
    resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/resources']
}
```

But it doen't work:

```
Error:Can't register given path of type 'SOURCE' because it's out of content root.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to combine two separate gradle projects together, then you should look at gradle [multi-project builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html). You will need to create a root project, which will include both your modules as subprojects and in that case, you can simply use one project as the dependency of another, like:

```
//service project dependencies
dependencies {
    compile project(':ProtocolLibrary')
    ...
}
```

After doing this, there is no reason to include sources from one project into another.

The second approach is to use the artifact, generated by ProtocolLibrary. You can make a dependency in Service project specifying the jar in filesystem, or your ProtocolLibrary could be published in your maven repo and be used as usual dependency.

Comment: I have not mentioned this in question (sorry), but I have 3 modules, which need to be built separetely (and they all depend on the ProtocolLibrary module). Are there any ways to configure 3 modules to build with different configuration and as different artifacts, but to depend on the library module?

Comment: @user3400841 You can build sub projects separately with different configurations and artifacts. But this sub projects can rely on each other artifact. Just read the user manual for that.